# How to fix ggplot continuous color range

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I can't fix the colors of my heat-maps according to their values. Same values should have same colors. The goal is to keep all values below a certain threshold (0.05) in (constant) gray. For values greather than this threshold, the colors should gradually change from "firebrick1" to "firebrick4".

For example, "Plant 5"/"202004" = 70.6 is red if I use variable `utilization2` and gray if I use variable `utilization`. How can I fix that?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

MONTHS <- str_c("2020", sprintf("%02d", 1:12))
PLANTS <- str_c("Plant ", 1:5)

crossing(month = MONTHS, plant = PLANTS) %>%
  mutate(utilization = runif(nrow(.), 70, 100)) %>%
  mutate(utilization2 = if_else(plant == "Plant 2", utilization * 0.67, utilization)) -> d

draw_plot <- function(fill) {
  fill <- ensym(fill)
   d %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = month, y = plant, fill = !!fill)) +
    geom_tile(aes(width = 0.85, height = 0.85)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(!!fill, 1)), color = "white") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkgray", "firebrick1", "firebrick4"), 
                         values = c(0, 0.05, 1)) +
    labs(x = "Month", y = "Production plant", title = str_c("fill = ", fill), color = "Utilization") +
    theme_light() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}
draw_plot(utilization)
draw_plot(utilization2)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

MONTHS <- str_c("2020", sprintf("%02d", 1:12))
PLANTS <- str_c("Plant ", 1:5)

crossing(month = MONTHS, plant = PLANTS) %>%
    mutate(utilization = runif(nrow(.), 70, 100)) %>%
    mutate(utilization2 = if_else(plant == "Plant 2", utilization * 0.67, utilization)) -> d

draw_plot <- function(fill) {
    fill <- ensym(fill)
    d %>%
        ggplot(mapping = aes(x = month, y = plant, fill = !!fill)) +
        geom_tile(aes(width = 0.85, height = 0.85)) +
        geom_text(aes(label = round(!!fill, 1)), color = "white") +
        scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
        scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
        scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkgray", "firebrick1", "firebrick4"),
                             values = c(0, 0.05, 1), limits = c(min(d$utilization, d$utilization2), max(d$utilization, d$utilization2))) +
        labs(x = "Month", y = "Production plant", title = str_c("fill = ", fill), color = "Utilization") +
        scale_color_identity() +
        theme_light() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
}
draw_plot(utilization)
draw_plot(utilization2)
```

The point is that `scale_fill_gradientn()` sets the limits of the scale to max and min of the vector of interest. You have to set them manually. In this case I chose both the max and min of both columns (`limits = c(min(d$utilization, d$utilization2), max(d$utilization, d$utilization2))`).

Answer (score 1):

The colours are interpolated between the values, so a trick you could do is is to set both `0` and `0.05` as gray, and begin the next colour at a very small increment to `0.05`.

```
draw_plot <- function(fill) {
  fill <- ensym(fill)
  d %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = month, y = plant, fill = !!fill)) +
    geom_tile(aes(width = 0.85, height = 0.85)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(!!fill, 1)), color = "white") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkgray", "darkgray", "firebrick1", "firebrick4"), 
                         values = c(0, 0.05, 0.05 + .Machine$double.eps, 1)) +
    labs(x = "Month", y = "Production plant", title = str_c("fill = ", fill), color = "Utilization") +
    theme_light() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}
draw_plot(utilization)
draw_plot(utilization2)
```

Maybe this is not necessary to mention, but the fill scale rescales all fill values to a range between 0-1 depending on the limits (see `?scales::rescale`), so the `0.05` you put in the `values` argument is the bottom 5% of the range value and not unscaled data values in `utilization` that are below 0.05. If you want to have consistent fill scales over multiple plots, you'd have to set the `limits` argument manually.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not seem to work for me. Did you intend to have all greys bellow 70.6 ? (Which is not the case).